# Find the 1st matching parent and update it with parent_id in business_table table in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this business table

```
ref_ID      name    parent_id 
-----------------------------
ABC-0001    Amb     NULL 
PQR-899     boss    NULL
tgv-632     pick    NULL
```

I want to update `parent_id` which is stored in another table `parent_customer`.

`parent_customer` table lists a hierarchy of data in which when both `ref_id` and `parent_id` are the same means it's the parent of the entire hierarchy.

For example:

```
4   PQR-899    PQR-899  this is ultimate parent of hierarchy
```

parent_customer

```
ID  ref_id     parent_id  
---------------------------
1   ABC-0001   opr-656
2   opr-656    ttK-668
3   ttK-668    ttK-668
4   PQR-899    PQR-899
5   kkk-565    AJY-567  
6   AJY-567    UXO-989
7   UXO-989    tgv-632
8   tgv-632    mnb-784 
9   mnb-784    qwe-525 
10  qwe-525    qwe-525
```

`match_table_CM`:

```
id    main_id
--------------
1     opr-656
2     PQR-899
3     tgv-632
4     mnb-784
```

You have to first match business table `ref_id` with `parent_customer`'s `ref_id`, and get the `parent_id`  and check if that parent id is in   `match_table_CM` (`main_id`), then update it with business table `parent_id`. Otherwise find the next parent check with main table. If all not found update it with last parent id.

For example: let's take `ABC-0001` from business table, its `parent_id` is NULL; check with `parent_customer` table's `ref_id` column, find the 1st record with 
`parent_id = opr-656`, then check with if that id exists in table `match_table_CM` (`1 opr-656`) - yes - then update business table (`parent_id`)
other wise check the next parent_customer hierarchy match parent_id ttK-668
check with match_table ... till you reach the top.(Exit when 1st match found and move to next id from business table )

Comment: I can't tell what results you are trying to achieve.

Comment: See one table(business table) i want to update with parent id. which is stored as a hirarchy in parent_customer.in this parent_customer table we have parent id which is same id as reference_id if the parent is same. i want to check before updating it check with match table if and only if id exist in this table then only update.

Comment: Just join all 3 tables and then do the update, it will ensure your logic from comment, check `sql server - update from join` query on SO

Comment: its not that easy bro try it. need to walk down hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your update like following.

```
update t 
set        t.parent_id = pc.parent_id 
from       [yourtble] t 
inner join parent_customer pc  on pc.ref_id = t.ref_id
where      exists 
           ( 
                  select 1 
                  from   match_table_cm 
                  where  main_id= pc.parent_id )
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below one. It will be helpful to you.

```
UPDATE bus
SET bus.parent_id = pc.ID
FROM tbl_buss bus
inner join parent_customer pc on pc.ref_id = bus.ref_id
inner join match_table_CM mt on mt.main_id = pc.parent_id
```

Thanks,
Amit Prajapati

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
UPDATE bt 
SET    bt.parent_id = pc.parent_id 
FROM   businesstable bt 
       INNER JOIN parent_customer pc ON pc.ref_id = bt.ref_id 
       INNER JOIN match_table_cm mt  ON mt.main_id = pc.parent_id
```

Output

```
+------------+------+------------+
|   ref_ID   | name | parent_id  |
+------------+------+------------+
| ABC-0001   | Amb  | opr-656    |
| PQR-899    | boss | PQR-899    |
| tgv-632    | pick | mnb-784    |
+------------+------+------------+
```

Online Demo: http://rextester.com/FAENX59383